# How to point domain with subdirectory to a specific YouTube URL?

Tags: domain, hosting, web-hosting

I have purchased a domain `netyou.info` in Godaddy. I wanted to point `netyou.info/design` to a specific URL (another web page) where I have a demo video.

At this point, I don't have a website having a sub-folder design. Do I need to build a website for adding a subdirectory `netyou.info/design`? or is there some way around I can add a subdirectory to the domain without a website?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for the [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't have a website having a sub-folder design.

DNS records map domains (e.g. `example.com`) to IP addresses (e.g. `1.2.3.4`). Paths ("subdirectories") for a domain (e.g. `/design`) are handled exclusively by web server software or the like (they have nothing to do with DNS).

> Do I need to build a website for adding a subdirectory (e.g. `example.com/design`)?

For this exact form, you need to have some piece of software (like a web server) handling HTTP requests and re-routing for the `/design` path, yes.

> Can I add a subdirectory to the domain without a website?

Not without additional software (as described above).

However, some possible answers might be:

1. If your GoDaddy account includes web hosting, use that.
2. If GoDaddy's web hosting or [virtual private server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) services are too expensive, you may be able to get web hosting or a virtual private server elsewhere for cheaper.
3. Look at [Keltari's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1658188/302907) and use a subdomain (e.g. `design.example.com`) instead. This has the advantages of A) not requiring any additional funds and B) being able to be set up entirely through GoDaddy (even without a web hosting package).

Answer (score -1):

In cPanel, create the "design" subdomain.

You can [modify](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file) the .htaccess file in that subdomain's document root to point to the URL.  If you do not know how to do this, GoDaddy support should be able to set this up for you.

Alternatively, you can just create an index.html file that redirects to a specific URL with the [meta tag](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/html-redirect).